# Applying for Schengen visa for the Netherlands to go to Germany

Tags: schengen-visas

I am studying in Germany but had to make an emergency trip to my home country. My visa will expire 3 days after my return to Germany. There are no early appointments available at the embassy. Can I apply for a short-term Schengen visa to the Netherlands and then go to Germany? The Schengen visa will help as I can apply for a temporary residence permit during this time.

Comment: I am not an expert on this particular topic, but what your are trying to do sounds like it goes strongly against the general visa application advice: the Dutch visa authorities will want to know why you want to visit the Netherlands and you have no good answer, which makes it likely that your visa will be denied. Did you check if it is actually a problem that your existing visa will expire 3 days after you return to Germany? Can you perhaps file an application for an extension with the "Ausländerbehörde" once you are back?

Comment: For how long are you going to be away? It may be possible that you already have to apply for a prolongation of your residence permits.

Comment: File for renewal of your study permit in advance (at least three months) whiles in Germany then request for Visa extension base on your intended absence from Germany. Visa extensions are issued the same day.

Answer (score 4):

Article 18 of the [Schengen Visa Code](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX:02009R0810-20160412) requires the Netherlands to refuse to process your application unless you are planning a visit to the Schengen area in which the Netherlands is your main destination, as defined in Article 5, so this plan is unlikely to succeed.

It's probably better to plan to make your temporary residence permit application during the three days after your return to Germany, but questions about that belong on [Expatriates](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com).